# Tem como criar um cron para excluir arquivos com datas retroativas?

Tags: linux, script, backup, cron

Vejam minha necessidade, tenho um cron que executa toda madrugada e cria um arquivo_ddmmaaaa.backup no servidor Linux Kubuntu, acontece que o HD vai enchendo rapidamente ja que esse arquivo de backup tem em media 500MB, como criar um cron que exclua arquivos uma data anterior a uma semana da data atual?

Fiquei pensando em como fazer isso mas não manjo muito do cron e como poderia colocar variaveis no cron, talvez a solução seja script, mas rs, também sou bem leigo em script.

O Script de excluir seria a grosso modo

delete /pasta/arquivo*.backup

Onde arquivo* seria com datas anteriores

Comment: Estava navegando nas perguntas do Stack e acabei por pensar numa solução, vou criar um script em php com minhas necessidades e executar no cron

Comment: Exatamente, o cron é somente um utilitário que executa tarefas programadas. Nao se programa nada nele além da periodicidade das tarefas que devem ser executadas.

Comment: Estava navegando nas perguntas do Stack e acabei por pensar numa solução, vou criar um script em php com minhas necessidades e executar no cron

Comment: what script @Marcelo ???

Comment: Sim um script em php já que nesse servidor tem um apache e php rodando :-)

Answer (score 1):

Você poderá utilizar o comando **[find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)** para buscar os arquivos antigos e depois remover-los.

`find /path/to -type f -mtime +7 -print0 | xargs -0 rm --`

Dessa forma, o comando irá listar todos os arquivos que foram modificados há, pelo menos, 7 dias atrás.

Você poderá substituir o parâmetro `-mtime` por `-atime` ou `-ctime`, que verifica a data da última vez que o arquivo foi acessado ou alterado, respectivamente.